# How to quit command prompt after a sleeping command executes?

Tags: bash, shell-script, background-process, sleep

I have a simple script:

```
f=1 # initial value
loop(){
...    
    if [[ $f -eq 1 ]]
    then
        echo $msg1
        f=2
        (sleep $interval; loop) &
        exit 1
    elif [[ $f -eq 2 ]]
    then
        echo $msg2
        f=1
        (sleep $interval; loop) &
        exit 2
    fi
...
}
```

It is intended to keep looping between these two messages one after the other. I am doing this, instead of a normal while loop, because I want the script to be in background. So, what I expected to happen in my terminal is:

```
gt@gt:~./timer.sh
<msg1>
gt@gt:~<me running some other commands>
<some output>
gt@gt:~<as soon as $interval time gets over>
<msg2>
gt@gt:~<fresh prompt>
```

As you can see, I would want the msg2 to appear where a normal echo output appears, and immediately after that it should leave a fresh prompt for command input. But what actually happens is:

```
gt@gt:~./timer.sh
<msg1>
gt@gt:~<me running some other commands>
<some output>
gt@gt:~<msg2>
<same prompt is still waiting for input here>
```

How to fix this?

You may locally verify this problem by running with `#!/bin/bash` and setting `sleep=3` seconds.

Comment: The fact that you observed `gt@gt:~<msg2>` is due to a race condition. It's not waiting for your prompt. Your background processes (which are unnecessarily too many) are connected to the same terminal emulator as your current shell. So, it just happened that your shell printed the prompt (which doesn't end with a line feed) just before one of the background processes printed msg2.

Comment: @NikoGambt Ok, I understand that. Could you please also explain how to fix it?

Comment: I have never done process synchronization in Bash. A dirty hack is to simply print a new line before each message. However, you should be more concerned about your code. It seriously needs to be refactored.

Comment: @NikoGambt I do not know how to further refactor it. Which part do you feel needs improvement? Also, even after printing a newline after the message, the same problem remains.

Comment: I'll leave that to other users who will actually give you answers that you need.

Comment: In general, this won't be possible. Both the script and your shell are two independent processes writing to the same terminal. Bash would have to know that some other process is writing to the terminal for it to create a new prompt.

Comment: @Olorin Oh...Is there something that needs to be changed in the timer creation process then?

Comment: Are you running (for example a server) with a text screen, or are you running with a graphical desktop environment? In the case of text screen you can run the different tasks in different 'screens' using the program `screen`. In the case of graphical desktop environment, you can run the tasks in different terminal windows.

Comment: @sudodus Hi, I am currently using a text based terminal like zsh. While I'll want the output to appear in the current terminal window itself, I am also open to the `notify-send` mode of output.

Comment: Are you running in a server that you log into remotely via `ssh` (or some similar program)? In that case, is it your own server or can you install programs in the server?

Comment: What do you mean my "me running some other commands"? I think it would be best to do that in another terminal window and let the two processes that you watch run in their own terminal windows and write there. -- If you have graphical capability, you can write messages (for example with `notify-send` or 'zenity`. Please explain what you have and what you might be able to modify, and we can work out a solution.

Comment: @sudodus "What do you mean my "me running some other commands"?" What I meant was that I should be able to continue my work in the same terminal in which I had run my timer script. The script should run in the background, and periodically as scheduled, send notifications to the terminal. I understand that it might not be possible to write to the terminal window, in case of which is there a solution using notify-send? And no sorry, I am not remotely logging into a server via `ssh`. Though, I am allowed to install programs like notify-send into the computer.

Comment: Your use of recursion will exhaust resources. I see nothing here that a loop could not do, but without resources exhaustion.

Comment: Your prompt is not re-drawn, but the shell is still waiting for a command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have your timer script send the `SIGINT` signal to the parent process (`$PPID`).

### Example

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Going to interrupt $PPID in 5 seconds"
sleep 5
echo "More output"
kill -SIGINT $PPID
sleep 5
```

When this script is run in the background (`./script &`) it should send output, sleep and then send more output followed by forcing the prompt to be redrawn.

The script will sleep again and then exit.

### Updating OP's Script

```
f=1 # initial value
loop(){
...    
    if [[ $f -eq 1 ]]
    then
        echo $msg1
        kill -SIGINT $PPID
        f=2
        (sleep $interval; loop) &
        exit 1
    elif [[ $f -eq 2 ]]
    then
        echo $msg2
        kill -SIGINT $PPID
        f=1
        (sleep $interval; loop) &
        exit 2
    fi
...
}
```

You will lose your line of pending input when your shell process is interrupted with the signal, but the command prompt will be redrawn after the timer script output.

### Edit

To reproduce this behavior in a child script, pass the parent PID environmental variable into the child script from the caller script.

`main.sh`

```
...
./timer.sh $PPID
...
#exits
```

`timer.sh`

```
...
# Save the parent pid argument
gp=$1
...
# Replace instances of $PPID with $gp in timer.sh
...
kill -SIGINT $gp
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. So, one problem here I encountered with this is that the code that I have shown above is called from another main script. So, it's like `./main.sh` allows user some choices. And if user takes choice X, `./timer.sh` is called from within `main.sh` and that `timer.sh` contains the `sleep` logic above. I believe, due to this situation, when I do `kill`, I get `./timer.sh: line 55: kill: (29423) - No such process` and the terminal prompt remains as it was (not redrawn). Is there any way to fix this specific issue?

Comment: @GaurangTandon So, `main.sh` calls the `timer.sh` process and then exits leaving the `timer.sh` running in the background?

Comment: Yep, that's what happens. There's no explicit `exit` statement in `main.sh` though, just that its last statement to execute is `./timer.sh`.

Comment: @GaurangTandon I added a new section to the answer that covers your use case.

Answer (score 2):

I think the following shellscript **`timer`** will do what you want or do something rather close to it.

```
#!/bin/bash

interval=60  # seconds
tips="Skip waiting with Yes|Enter, exit with No|Escape"
msg1="First message ...

$tips"
msg2="Second message ...

$tips"

f=1 # initial value
while true
do
    if [[ $f -eq 1 ]]
    then
#        zenity --notification --text="$msg1" 2> /dev/null
        LANG=C zenity --question --title="${0##*/}" \
        --text="$msg1" --timeout="$interval" --width=400 2> /dev/null
    elif [[ $f -eq -1 ]]
    then
#        zenity --notification --text="$msg2" 2> /dev/null
        LANG=C zenity --question --title="${0##*/}" \
        --text="$msg2" --timeout="$interval" --width=400 2> /dev/null
    fi
    ans=$?
    if [ $ans -eq 0 ] || [ $ans -eq 5 ]
    then
     f=$((-f))
    else
      zenity --info --title="${0##*/}" \
        --text="Exiting now" --timeout="3" 2> /dev/null
     break
    fi
done & pid=$!

echo "kill with
kill $pid       # useful during testing 
--------------------------------------------"
```

- I use **`zenity --question`** to send the messages, which should be OK, if they come seldom, and you really want to notice them (and probably do something). This way you can also exit gracefully from the background task.

  [image]
- Uncomment the **`zenity --notification`** commands, and comment away the `zenity --question` commands, if you want less intrusive messages.

  You should also enter `sleep $interval` command lines after the `zenity --notification` lines.

  But that also means that you have to kill the background process by using its process number,

  ```
  kill <process number>
  ```

  The actual process number is shown, when you start the timer shellscript, and you can find it via `ps`

  ```
  $ ./timer
  kill with
  kill 15585       # useful during testing 
  --------------------------------------------
  $ ps -e |grep timer
  15585 pts/3    00:00:00 timer
  ```

Comment: Hi, though I was primarily looking for a non-prompt based approach, I'm glad you posted this option anyway as a fallback just in case the text based approach never works out. Thanks :)

Comment: @GaurangTandon, You are welcome. I hope you find a solution, that will make you happy in the end :-)